# How to OAuth Twitter with httplib2 and Python 3.x?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, python-3.x, httplib2

I know there are a lot of Python Twitter API and OAuth wrappers out there, but I don't want to use them. I want to use nothing more than httplib2 and Python 3.x standard library. Could you please demonstrate simple code examples on how to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should we write the code for you? Do it yourself, and come back with a real question.

Comment: Word. There is no such thing as a "simple code example" for doing something as big as implementing an oAuth client from scratch. Read the specifications, read other python libraries. And get to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2). [The main implementation code](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py) is very readable. Since there are a lot of thorny issues here like precisely how you encode your forms it is tricky to get right. I would recommend just using the oauth2 library, that is what I've done to integrate with Twitter (httplib2 + oauth2 + Twitter's REST/streaming APIs).